# calculate grand total of items in ngFor with ionic and angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

i'm displaying list of items in a cart using ngFor and i'm able to calculate the sub total against each item in the cart by multiplying the price with the quantity, now the issue is how to get the grand total at the bottom of the list

HMTL

```
 <ion-item *ngFor="let item of productServices.itemsInCart">
      <ion-note slot="end"> <span style="font-size: 20px; position: relative; top:15px">GHc {{item.price * item.quantity}}</span></ion-note>
      <ion-thumbnail slot="start">
        <img src="/assets/imgs/{{item.img}}"/>
      </ion-thumbnail>
      <ion-label text-wrap>
        <h2>{{item.name}}</h2>
      </ion-label>

    </ion-item>
    <span>GHc{{totalSum}}</span>
```

Javascript

```
    getTotalCost() {
      let total = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < this.itemsInCart.length; i++) {
      this.itemsInCart[i].price;
              this.totalSum = this.itemsInCart[i].price * this.itemsInCart[i].quantity;
          }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
getTotalCost() {
      let total = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < this.itemsInCart.length; i++) {
      this.itemsInCart[i].price;
              this.totalSum = this.itemsInCart[i].price * this.itemsInCart[i].quantity;
              total = total + this.totalSum
          }

    return total;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//I assume that In component class there is a variable 'totalSum' to display the total cost in view.  

    public totalSum = this.getTotalCost();

          getTotalCost() {
              let total = 0
              for (var i = 0; i < this.itemsInCart.length; i++) {
                      total =  total + this.itemsInCart[i].price * this.itemsInCart[i].quantity;
                  }
                 return total;
          }
```